# cannot find the nanosleep function when cross compile configure

Tags: c++, gcc, cross-compiling

I use toolchain from [here](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu/11.2-2022.02/binrel/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz), then extract to gcc11_arm_armv7_none_gnueabihf,

below is command:

```
export ASFLAGS='-march=armv7-a -fPIC -fstack-protector -Wall -fno-omit-frame-pointer --sysroot=gcc11_arm_armv7_none_gnueabihf/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/libc -no-canonical-prefixes  -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -D__DATE__=redacted -D__TIMESTAMP__=redacted -D__TIME__=redacted -g3'
export CFLAGS='-march=armv7-a -fPIC -fstack-protector -Wall -fno-omit-frame-pointer --sysroot=gcc11_arm_armv7_none_gnueabihf/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/libc -std=c99 -no-canonical-prefixes  -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -D__DATE__=redacted -D__TIMESTAMP__=redacted -D__TIME__=redacted -g3'
export CXXFLAGS='-march=armv7-a -fPIC -fstack-protector -Wall -fno-omit-frame-pointer --sysroot=gcc11_arm_armv7_none_gnueabihf/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/libc -std=c++11 -no-canonical-prefixes  -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -D__DATE__=redacted -D__TIMESTAMP__=redacted -D__TIME__=redacted -g3'
export LDFLAGS='-lstdc++ -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -pass-exit-codes -lm -Wall --sysroot=gcc11_arm_armv7_none_gnueabihf/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/libc -lpthread'

export AR=gcc11_arm_armv7_none_gnueabihf/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ar
export CC=gcc11_arm_armv7_none_gnueabihf/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
export CXX=gcc11_arm_armv7_none_gnueabihf/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
export LD=gcc11_arm_armv7_none_gnueabihf/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-ld
./configure
......
......
checking if nanosleep requires any libraries... configure: error: cannot find the nanosleep function
```

I can find nanosleep function in gcc11_arm_armv7_none_gnueabihf/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/time.h, but it's a extern declaration, do I need pass something to compiler to let it know where to find nanosleep definition?

Comment: Try `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199309L`. BTW `-lpthread` is probably not what you want, you should use `-pthread` when both compiling and linking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nanosleep` requires `_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 199309L` feature macro as specified by `man nanosleep`.

Try adding `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L` before `#include <time.h>`.

Comment: aslo can use -std=gnu++xx

Comment: @xiedeacc Yes, that will work too, although it does much more than that and allows non-standard C code to compile. Might not be desired if you need to preserve compatibility.